# disable dijit menu conditionally

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to add the property `disabled: true` or nothing at all conditionally depending on the value of `on` like that:

```
        var on = true;
        pMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
          label: "Disabled menu item",
            if(on){
              return disabled: true;
            }
        }));
```

This seems to return an error in the console "number is not a function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
    var on = true;
    pMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Disabled menu item",
        disabled: on ? true : false
    }));
```

If `on` is really meant to be a `boolean`-value in your usecase, you can also just assign it to to disabled like `disabled: on`, thats it. But as far as i know, you can not execute statements (like an `if`-cascade in a non constructor object declaration like `{}` does.

As `disabled` is `false` by default, this is actually like adding nothing at all, but it becomes more readable in my personal opinion.

Think about it: you don't add a property to the instance, you actually just want to set a value to a propery that's already there.